# Copying many large files from R to a new SQL db

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, loops, file-copying

I have 6,000 files on a server, each 11M rows of a single column. As I understand it there are 3 steps:

1. Connect to a SQL DB
2. Read in the files
3. Write them to the SQL DB

So I think I've connected to the db:

```
sqlconnect <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "~/folder/portal-database-output.sqlite")
my_db_file <- "~/folder/portal-database-output.sqlite"
my_db <- src_sqlite(my_db_file, create = TRUE)
```

And then I need to read in each file and then copy it to the SQL DB. I was thinking of creating a list of files (all .Rds in the folder) and then doing a map or loop that creates a df, copies to the DB, and then repeats x6000. How can I code this?

Should I instead be trying to do a Bulk Insert? If so, how do I do so?

Finally, I haven't decided if the result should be a single table 6000 wide or 6000 tables -- I don't have enough experience with SQL to determine what would be easier.

Comment: When you have 6.000 files with each 11.000.000 rows = in total 66.000.000.000 rows. Thats a lot. Before deciding to have 6.000 tables or only one single table, it would be interesting to know a bit more about the structure /info with the files. Is the file content always the same? For example machine temperature over a time of 6.000 days? Or different context? Which data do you have? A string with a length of x or only a temperature value? Than we could calculate such a table and help deciding the structure of the database..

Comment: Each file is identical -- each row has a numeric value

Comment: Is the column name of numeric value in each file the same? Please provide context as @STORM is asking.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the column name is the same in each file

Comment: @SamKoss In this case i would read all files from the folder and insert into one single table.